# Jenkins Pipeline - How to maintain over time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I am currently using [Cloudbees Jenkins Core](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-core)as my Jenkins solution.

I am using [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) to write our Jenkins job configuration. These pipelines are stored in GitHub repositories. Each Jenkins job when created is connected to a GitHub Repository where the source code is pulled from, and that's where the Jenkinsfile is stored and Jenkins reads from.

Below are some high-level photos for how our Jenkins jobs are configured.

[image: Jenkins Job Configuration One]

[image: Jenkins Job Configuration Two]

The advantage of the way these jobs are configured is the `Jenkinsfile` is always read from the master branch. Meaning if a rouge developer tries to remove stages from the `Jenkinsfile` from within their own branch, it doesn't matter because the `Jenkinsfile` is always read from the master branch (which is always protected).

However, the one **massive** drawback to this - is how do teams and developers who are devops engineers make changes to the `Jenkinsfile`? For example, let's say a developer creates a branch called `feature-jenkins-search` and they edit the Jenkinsfile adding a new stage in the pipeline. Whenever they push these changes to GitHub to test - they can't test as it's always read from the master branch? Meaning devops engineerings have to work directly on the master branch? **Surely** this is not the best way to go and there is a better configuration to set?

Comment: Devops is a **Is a very delicate piece** in corporations. If some developer **change or damage** the pipeline, new software release or entire continuous delivery could be affected.  Give me an example of your pipeline steps and I could share my approach.

Comment: What do you mean Pipeline Steps? We have stages such as npm test, Snyk security testing, checkmarx security testing, version check in the package.json. They are a few examples. we just need an appropriate way for teams to develop and build out pipelines, which still making sure that if they merge into another branch, it reads the Jenkinsfile from the *target* branch. E.G master if they are trying to push into master :)

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into the [Jenkins multi-branch pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) feature. The Jenkins multi-branch pipeline allows to create a single configuration item in Jenkins (a bit like a folder) that can detect all the branches and pull requests in a GitHub repository with a Jenkinsfile and build them using automatically created jobs. Inside this multi-branch pipeline object when it is configured in Jenkins, you will find a number of jobs to build the various branches and pull-requests in the GitHub repository.

So your developers should maintain a Jenkinsfile in every branch they work on in GitHub to build that branch in your Jenkins server.

It is possible to make the Jenkinsfile do branch specific handling if required with conditional stages / when conditions in the Jenkinsfile pipelines in each branch.

You can lock down the master branch so that code and Jenkinsfile changes from other branches can only be merged with an approved PR (pull request). There is good integration between Jenkins and GitHub such that you can configure the master branch to only allow a PR to be merged if the PR is buildable in Jenkins. So if developers add new stages / processing to a Jenkinsfile on a branch being merged to master, it should be validated so that builds of your master branch are not broken.

There is a lot of configurability in the Jenkins multi-branch pipeline object for detection and handling of branches and it may be necessary to experiment to get it right for what you need with your team. If you cannot find this feature in Jenkins, it is probably because the correct Jenkins pipeline and GitHub related plugins are not installed.

You could also have a look at a similar Jenkins feature called the Jenkins GitHub Organization Folder which allows to detect and build all repos and branches at a GitHub Organization level. But when starting out, I would suggest to look into the multi-branch pipeline at the single repo level first.

These features are discussed in the Jenkins [pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline-as-code/). We use these features with our internal GitHub and Jenkins server and it works very well.

I think you will find the idea of using a single Jenkinsfile in the master branch to be used for building all branches is unworkable, as you have seen!

Comment: Just looked at your screenshots on a larger screen and saw that you are using the GH org feature. I think you need to trust devs to config the Jenkinsfile on the branches and let them build in Jenkins..

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am more than happy to let devs to config the Jenkinsfile on the branches, but what happens if they just remove the whole thing, and remove the pipeline and put `echo "hello"` which would pass the build - and then they try and merge that into master? I am happy to let them dev, but is there a way of setting a GitHub Organisation so that if a PR is opened it reads the Jenkinsfile from the target branch? E.G master if they are merging into master - thanks.

Comment: For the PR it‘ll show all the differences. In case so reviews the PR you‘d see that so changed the Jenkinsfile in some unwanted way. If you do not do reviews it would be really difficult to detect such changes. Reading the Jenkinsfile from the target branch would no longer allow to propagate changes to the Jenkinsfile in the source branch. Think without a review you won’t be able to notice such changes.